# move along a grid in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I can set four different movement directions for my player

- Vector2.up => (0,1)
- Vector2.down => (0,-1)
- Vector2.left => (-1,0)
- Vector2.right => (1,0)

and I have a two dimensional array that contains `Cell` objects

```
public class Cell
{
    public Cell(GameObject cellObject, bool isObstacle)
    {
        CellObject = cellObject;
        IsObstacle = isObstacle;
    }

    public GameObject CellObject { get; set; }

    public bool IsObstacle { get; set; }
}
```

My array is initialized by the size of the map.

```
private const int MAP_SIZE = 10;
private Cell[,] mapCells = new Cell[MAP_SIZE, MAP_SIZE];
```

I fill this array by using two loops, this will give me 100 cells.

```
for (int x = 0; x < MAP_SIZE; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < MAP_SIZE; y++)
    {
        Vector3 newCellPosition = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        GameObject newCellObject = Instantiate(cell, newCellPosition, cell.transform.rotation);

        bool isObstacle = false; // TEST

        Cell newCell = new Cell(newCellObject, isObstacle);
        mapCells[x, y] = newCell;
    }
}
```

When moving the player I want to return the `Cell` he has to move to. The movementDirection parameter will set the row and the column to search for.

If there is an obstacle cell the player should just move to this obstacle and stop.

[image: Path]

```
public Cell GetTargetCell(Vector2 movementDirection)
{
    Cell targetCell = null;

    // get the path

    // get the closest obstacle

    return targetCell;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to calculate the correct target cell by a 2D direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most elegant way of doing it is by using two separate for loops and the [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

```
//returns cell
Cell GetTargetCell(Vector2 dir)
{
    if(dir.y == 0) //if we're going horizontal
    {
        //HorizontalMovement
        for(int i = 0; i < ((dir.x==1)?mapSize-PLAYER_X:PLAYER_X); i++)
        {
            if(mapCells[(int)dir.x*i,PLAYER_Y].IsObstacle()) //if we encounter an obstacle
                return mapCells[(int)dir.x*i,PLAYER_Y]; //return cell that's an obstacle
        }

        //if we didn't encounter an obstacle
        return mapCells[(dir.x == 1)?mapSize:0,PLAYER_Y]; //return the cell
    }
    else if(dir.x == 0)
    {
        //VerticalMovement
        //copy paste the previous for loop and edit the parameters, I'm too lazy :P
    }
    else
    {
        //NoMovement
        Debug.Log("Please enter a valid Direction");
        return mapCells[0,0];
    }


}
```

Replace the PLAYER_X and PLAYER_Y values, with the x, and y values of the cell the player is currently in. I didn't check if the code contains any errors, but I think it should work.

Comment: Your code looks confusing to me so I tried to convert it into "simpler" code but both codes throw errors. Using my example gets me an out of range exception when moving up or right https://hastebin.com/ihanocihos.cs

Comment: I assume you only get the out of range exception when the player doesn't find an obstacle. You can fix this by changeing

if (moveRight)
            {
                cellIndexHorizontal = MAP_SIZE;
            }

to

if (moveRight)
            {
                cellIndexHorizontal = MAP_SIZE-1;
            }

and do the same for the vertical.

The error occurs since arrays start counting at zero

Comment: Yes I tried this way out but then other out of range problems appear. Something is wrong there

Comment: Strange, when I read your code I can't find out in which cases it would give out of range exceptions. Can you briefly describe what you do and post the error message along with it?

Comment: if you want, I can give you access to my Github repository. It's a fresh one with only this code working in Unity. Just if you would like and want to test the code in Unity

Comment: yeah sure, send me the link

Comment: Okay I found out why the error occured. I highlighted the part of the code, I changed to fix the error. https://pastebin.com/W8B37EFS . I didn't fix the error for going down (but it is the same type of error that occured when going left). A couple of tips for debugging: If you double click the error message in the unity console, it will open Visual Studio and select the line of code where the error occured. You can use Debug.Log() to write to the console. e.g. Debug.Log(varA); will output the value of varA to the console.